# Changing <a href> dynamically in jquery Teleric grid MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik-grid

Hello I am working on Teleric grid in mvc3

I want to change href of "a" tag dynamically

Below is my code

```
 function onRowDataBound(e) {

    if (e.dataItem.AffiliateId == 1) {

      var id=e.dataItem.Id; 

 e.row.cells[0].innerHTML ="<a href=\"@Url.Content("~/Customer/Address/List/"+id)\"  target=_blank>nxn v</a>";

        e.row.cells[0].style["color"] = "red";
    }
```

But error is id does not exist in current context

Any Solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Url.Content() call is executed at the time your View is parsed and sent to the browser.
Javascript is executed when the grid actually renders in the browser (much later).

All this

```
@Url.Content("~/Customer/Address/List/"+id)
```

is C#-code. You cannot access Javascript variables in C# code or vice versa.

What you need to do is generate the URL without the id and concatenate in Javascript:

```
e.row.cells[0].innerHTML ="<a href=\"@Url.Content("~/Customer/Address/List/")"+ id +"\"  target=_blank>nxn v</a>";
```